# retrive data angular firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
this.studentObservable = this.studentDetailsService.readStudentDatabase( user.uid ) as Observable<StudentDetails> ;

this.studentObservable.subscribe( temp => {
         this.student = temp as StudentDetails ;
    });
```

I have retrieved a data collection from firestore.
and this `this.student` has a property called `eventId`. I need to retrieve that `eventId`'s document from firestore. how to do that without subscribing inside the subscribe ??

Comment: can you more code and what you trying to here

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to prevent callback hell (nested subscribes).

**1. call your next http call via a method.**

```
this.studentObservable.subscribe(temp => {
  this.student = temp as StudentDetails;
  this.subscribeSomething();
});
subscribeSomething(): void { this.somethingObservable(this.student).subscribe(() => {}); }
```

**2. use promises**

```
async method(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    this.student = await this.studentObservable.toPromise();
  } catch(e) {
    throw Error(e);
  }
  try {
    const res = await this.anotherHttpToPromise(this.student);
  } catch(e) {
    throw Error(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give me a wat to unpack studentObservable to a normal object , that i can use anywhere?

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

***You can get Data inside Map Before where you can make your logic what you trying to do***

```
this.studentObservable = this.studentDetailsService.readStudentDatabase( user.uid ) as Observable<StudentDetails> ;

this.studentObservable
.pipe(map(data))
.subscribe( data => {
         this.student = temp as StudentDetails ;
    });
```

Comment: in map(data) , what is data ?

Comment: what is the advantage of doing this ?

Comment: this way you can get data before subscribe method  and transform into any logic